# I want to make an accordion, how to fix that row table sub?

Tags: angular, typescript, accordion

I recently tried using angular, and I want to add accordion at table, and my table sub appear in each row..how to fix it?

Typescript Code

```
constructor(
    ...
    protected labarugiReport: ReportLabarugiService
) { }

ngOnInit(){}
...

isActive(id) {
   return this.selected === id;
}

async getSub(id:any){
     this.selected = (this.selected === id ? null : id);
     let dateEnd = new Date(this.dateEnd.value);
     let dateStart = new Date(this.date.value);
     this.itemSoldSub3 = await this.labarugiReport.getReoportListSoldItemByCategoryAll(this.user.principle.id, id, this.getDate(dateStart), this.getDate(dateEnd));
}
```

My Scss code

```
.table-container {
    .activetab {
        display: block !important;
    }

}
```

html code  which I modified from other question

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of itemSoldSub2;let i=index" [ngClass]="{activetab: isActive(data.categoryId)}">
         <div (click)="getSub(data.categoryId);">

               <div *ngIf = "data.categoryName">
                        <td style="border-bottom: none;">{{data.categoryName}}</td>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf = "!data.categoryName">
                          <td style="border-bottom: none;">Uncategorized</td>
                        </div>
                      <td style="border-bottom: none;">{{data.sumPrice}}</td>
               </div>
                <!-- </tr> -->
               <table>
                  <tbody [ngClass]="{activetab: isActive(data.categoryId)}">
                      <tr *ngFor="let sub of itemSoldSub3">
                          <td>{{sub.itemName}}</td>
                          <td>{{sub.sumTotalPrice}}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you create a stackblitz, or please explain what's your issue.

Comment: @BearNithi my problem is that accordion appears on every row

Comment: @BearNithi the problem is  -> list data from itemSoldSub3 appears on every row

Comment: That's what you want right? Accordion in each row? Or am I missing something?
A simple view of what you are trying to accomplish will also help.

Comment: @emkay I want the accordion to appear only in the row that I have clicked on

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition on this line

```
 <div (click)="getSub(data.categoryId);" *ngIf="data.showAccordion">
```

Inside the method getSub(), make data.showAccordion when user clicks, true. 
You will need to add a property showAccordion in your json 'data'. 
Right now it doesn't work because there is no condition I can find to hide the entire accordion. If this doesn't help I would recommend, you provide simple diagram to show what you are trying to achieve.